# Hadith on non menstrual bleeding

Tags: hadith-interpretation, menses

Can someone shed some context on this hadith? What is meant by a "kick in the womb":

> It was narrated from Aisha that Umm Habibah bint Jahsh who was married
> to ‘Abdur-Rahman bin ‘Awf suffered from Istihadah (non-mentrual
> vaginal bleeding) and did not become pure. Her situation was mentioned
> to the Messenger of Allah and he said: ‘That is not menstruation,
> rather it is a kick in the womb, so let her work out the length of the
> menses that she used to have, and stop praying, then after that let
> her perform Ghusl for every prayer.'”
>
> [Sunan Al-Nasa’i 210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4DZv.jpg)

Comment: On topics like this, please add more tags that are relevant, like [menstrual], etc.

Comment: I only requested the context of the hadith and I don't have enough reputation to make a menstrual tag which doesn't currently exist.

Comment: Fair enough, then.

Comment: Before creating a tag it is better to check whether it could fit in an existing one. we have a lot of one-time tags.

Comment: Are you asking about this specific hadith? Or the whole lot of sahih narrations on the same incident using a different and easier wording? See for example amon the search results [here](https://sunnah.com/search?q=%D8%A5%D9%90%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%87%D9%8E%D8%A7+%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D8%B3%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%92+%D8%A8%D9%90%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D8%B6%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%90+%D9%88%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%90%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%87%D9%8E%D8%A7)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Both.

Answer (score 0):

It was narrated from 'Aishah that Umm Habibah bint Jahsh who was married to 'Abdur-Rahman bin 'Awf suffered from Istihadah (non-mentrual vaginal bleeding) and did not become pure. Her situation was mentioned to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and he said:

> 'That is not menstruation, rather it is a kick in the womb, so let
> her work out the length of the menses that she used to have, and stop
> praying (for that period of tie), then after that period of time),
> then after that let her perform Ghusl for every prayer.'"A kick
> in the womb: in other narrations means ***"A kick from Shaitan,", meaning
> that the Shaitan uses it to confuse her about her religious
> commitment***.
>
> Sunan an-Nasa'i https://sunnah.com/urn/1102110

The above hadith has answered your question. Here,  ***"A kick in the womb", in other narrations means "A kick from Shaitan,"*** meaning that the Shaitan uses it to confuse her about her religious commitment.

## Explanation :-

The devil (satan) is always vigilant and never ceases attempts to mislead us from the straight path.
Our beloved Prophet (PBUH) said in an authentic hadith that,

> Jabir reported:
>
> I heard Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) as saying: "The Satan is present with any
> one of you in everything he does; he is present even when he eats
> food..........." https://sunnah.com/muslim:2033d

The devil has full control over human's heart. Whenever we remember Allah, the satan withdraws. And this is how Satan deceives us in thousands of ways.
Since Allah has given Muhammad(PBUH) such information about Satan and that's why he(PUBH) has uttered the above phrase which is "A kick in the womb" meaning that ***the Shaitan uses it(Istihadah) to confuse her about her religious commitment.***

And Wallahu 'alam

Comment: What is the source of "A kick in the womb", in other narrations means "A kick from Shaitan,"? This comment is not part of the hadith, but something the editor or translator added. This deviation was not reported via 'Aishah, but appears in ahadith in the remaining Sunan books and by imam Ahmad -all of which were qualified as da'if by al-Albani- and in al-Muwatta' as a a fatwa from ibn 'Umar.